# AWS IAM - allow access with temporary password to specific bucket

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am wondering if anyone has an example of connecting to an S3 bucket with a temporary password to give that user access to some objects with C#.

I have not found any samples of this anywhere.

It looks like REST is used and a request would need to be created but I am in need of some direction for those in the know....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pre-signed query string authentication:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2488-Generating-Pre-Signed-Query-String-Authentication-Amazon-S3-Urls-With-User-Specific-Data.htm